# EJB 3 injection into spring beans

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I've made a mavenized web  application with spring, spring security... Now, I want to add ejb module for  database access, I was looking on the internet but I didn't find something clear because it's my first time with EJB.
I want to use something like @EJB in my controller
like"

```
@Stateless(name = "CustomerServiceImpl")
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService 


@EJB
private MyEjb myEjb;
```

and how can I configure it in spring context if there is a tutorial or any other help. It will be great and thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To inject your ejb 3 bean in spring bean you can follow below steps.
1. Create your Spring bean 
2. Create your EJB with its Remote and Local Interface
3. Write Implementations class
e.g.

```
package com.ejb;
@Local
public interface MyEjbLocal{
       public String sendMessage();
}

package com.ejb;
@Remote
public interface MyEjbRemote{
       public String sendMessage();
}

@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/MessageSender")
public class MyEjbImpl implements MyEjbLocal, MyEjbRemote{
 public String sendMessage(){
   return "Hello";   
 }
}
```

above is the example of EJB3 which uses both remote and local interface

Now we create the Spring bean in which we inject this ejb.

```
package com.ejb;

@Service
public class MyService {

   private MyEjbLocal ejb;

   public void setMyEjbLocal(MyEjbLocal ejb){
        this.ejb = ejb;
  }

  public MyEjbLocal getMyEjbLocal(){
       return ejb;
  }
}
```

We have added the instance of ejb in spring however we need to inject this in spring's spring-config.xml.
There are 2 ways to inject the ejb in spring bean

1. First Way

```xml
<bean id ="myBean" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStetelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
       <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/MessageSender#com.ejb.MyEjb=Local />
       <property name="businessInterface" value="com.ejb.MyEjbLocal" />
</bean>
```

Note: I have used the Local interface here you can use Remote as per your need.

2. Another way of injecting the ejb is

```xml
<jee:remote-slsb id="messageSender"
jndi-name="ejb/MessageSender#com.ejb.MyEjbLocal"
           business-interface="com.ejb.MyEjbLocal"
           home-interface="com.ejb.MyEjbLocal"
           cache-home="false" lookup-home-on-startup="false"
           refresh-home-on-connect-failure="true" />
```

So when the bean get initialized at that time the ejb will get injected in your spring bean.

Comment: The First Way works for me! Thanks! But BEWARE that the LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean is misspelled in the first example. I had to face a ClassNotFoundException for a while until I realized it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#ejb-access-local

You can inject EJB using setter injection. Configure your bean this way:

```xml
<bean id="myComponent" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/myBean"/>
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.mycom.MyComponent"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myController" class="com.mycom.myController">
    <property name="myComponent" ref="myComponent"/>
</bean>
```

You can also use `<jee:local-slsb>` tag to be able to inject your EJB:

```xml
<jee:local-slsb id="myComponent" jndi-name="ejb/myBean"
        business-interface="com.mycom.MyComponent"/>

<bean id="myController" class="com.mycom.myController">
    <property name="myComponent" ref="myComponent"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I'v tried this but jboss keep  telling me that he can't find jndi name ... so i deleted this and i just used @EJB nothing more and everything works fine !!!! is that correct ? NB : my war use ejb module as dependencie