# How can I inject an EJB with no interface into a Spring bean?

Tags: spring, ejb-3.1

I have several EJB 3.x stateless session beans, which have no interfaces defined. I need to inject these beans into a Spring bean, but am unable to do so.

No interface EJB:

```
@Singleton
public class MyNoInterfaceEJB {
   public String sayHello() { return "hi"; }
}
```

My bean:

```
@Named
public class MyEJBClientBean {
   @EJB
   private MyNoInterfaceEJB testejb;

   // ...
}
```

And my bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <jee:local-slsb id="testejb" jndi-name="java:global/MyEAR/MyModule/MyProject!com.test.MyNoInterfaceEJB"
            business-interface="com.test.MyNoInterfaceEJB"/>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />
 </beans>
```

On initialization of the spring container, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'testejb': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [com.test.MyNoInterfaceEJB] is not an interface
```

The exception itself is very clear -- the spring container is expecting that my bean has a local interface view as it's business-interface; however, I don't have one (and can not introduce one).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is the closest related question I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008810/ejb-3-injection-into-spring-beans -- but it requires using the Remote and Local Interface views, which isn't an option for me.

Comment: EJB, CDI (as implied by `@Named`. Thus, what you say, "Controllers" are now governed by CDI and not by Spring), JPA etc which you are supposed to use are part of Java EE. What makes you still stick to Spring i.e. what features do you use from Spring which are not available in Java EE? (This is not controversial but a general use-case).

Answer (score 0):

The exception is a result of the `<jee:local-slsb>` element in your spring configuration file. you provide the implementation class in the business-interface attribute of the element.

I'm not sure whether Spring is able to handle the @EJB annotation in your spring bean. If not you can let your spring bean implement the Spring interface `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` and do a programmatic JNDI lookup for the no interface EJB.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes - that's the direction I'm heading in... it would just be much simpler if I could have Spring autowire the EJB using a no-interface view...

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to specify the mapped name on the @EJB annotation, and remove the local-slsb declaration from bean.xml

I don't know why Spring needs the mapped name or is not able to figure it out on it's own. Fish it out of the debug logs from the application server if you don't know it already.

```
@Named
public class MyEJBClientBean {

    @EJB(mappedName="java:global/MyApp/MyModule/MyNoInterfaceEJB!com.initech.MyNoInterfaceEJB ")
    private MyNoInterfaceEJB testejb;

  // ...
```

}

The example above is the full name in a full EAR, it might be bound to "shorter" jndi-names too if there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:app/domains/BaseDao" expected-type="com.project.core.persistence.baseDaoImpl.BaseDao" id="baseDao" ></jee:jndi-lookup>
```

Then, you can inject it with @Autowire annotation or declare in your bean.

```
<Bean class ="com.project.springBean" id ="myBean">
<property name="baseDao" ref="baseDao" />
or 
@Component
public class SpringBean {
@AutoWired
private BaseDao baseDao;
public void setBaseDao(BaseDao baseDao) {
this.baseDao =baseDao;
```

}
If you use autowire or not you should have setter method for baseDao in your springBean class.

Answer (score -1):

It should be ok if you simply declare a bean of type `MyNoInterfaceEJB`, using any means you wish. I did it like that, in my configuration class:

```
@Bean public MyNoInterfaceEJB myEjb()
{
  return new MyNoInterfaceEJB();
}
```

If you removed the `<jee:local-slsb>` definition you should get a different error message, simply requiring a bean of type `MyNoInterfaceEJB`. That's what you do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that EJBs should never be instantiated with `new`. In this case you could  look it up using the InitialContext, if you don't want to use the @EJB annotation.