# Accessing a remote ejb from spring

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I have an old spring app, and I want to update it to use a jndi looked up ejb.

The old spring app has a config file defining beans like so :

```
<bean id="myBean" class="uk.co.mycompany.mypackage">
        <property name="dependentDao" ref="myOtherDaoBean"/>
    </bean>
```

In my new applications I use ejbs to looked up like so :

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/myApp/myModule/MyOtherDaoBean!uk.co.mycompany.mypackage.MyOtherDaoBeanImpl")
private MyOtherDaoBean myOtherDaoBean;
```

How can I specify the spring app to use the new way ?  I can include the bean interfaces as a dependent jar, but I want the runtime instance looked up using jndi.

Comment: You mean you want to use Spring and EJB together in one app or invoke remotely EJB from old Spring app? Was `myOtherDaoBean` a Spring bean or EJB so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EJB 3 injection into spring beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008810/ejb-3-injection-into-spring-beans)