# Inject EJB 3.0 in spring 2.0 controller on websphere is throwing exception

Tags: spring, websphere, ejb-3.0

I'd like to call an EJB service from my spring bean. I have tried many ways like the below and deployed on websphere, but it gives me exception in jndi names. Can anyone help?

## Spring bean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd">


 <bean id="ejbService" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/EjbServiceImpl"/>
        <property name="businessInterface" value="com.services.EjbService"/>
    </bean>  
<bean id="springController" class="com.controllers.SpringController" scope="session">
    <property name="eService" ref="ejbService"/>                
    </bean>

</beans>
```

## Spring controller

```
public class SpringController {

    private EjbService eService;

    public void setOrders(Order order) { 
        eService.liquidPortfolio(order);
    }

    public EjbService  getEService() {
        return eService;
    }

    public void setEService (
        EjbService  eService) {
        this.eService = eService;
    }
}
```

## EJB

```
@Local
public class EjbService {
    @Asynchronous
    public void setOrders(Order order) ;
}

@Stateless
@Singleton
public class EjbServiceImpl implements EjbService{

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(" init method");
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void setOrders(Order order) {        
        System.out.println(" order=" + order);
    }   
}
```

## Exception

```
[4/3/16 9:44:30:708 AST] 0000007a ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ejbService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/my-web-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: WSRUHHQ830Node01Cell/nodes/WSRUHHQ830Node01/servers/server1, name: ejb/EjbServiceImpl: First component in name EjbServiceImpl not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: WSRUHHQ830Node01Cell/nodes/WSRUHHQ830Node01/servers/server1, name: ejb/EjbServiceImpl: First component in name EjbServiceImpl not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4564)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1822)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1777)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1434)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:616)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:423)

Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2169)
    at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2958)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2954)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:871)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2952)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1818)
```

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008810/ejb-3-injection-into-spring-beans

Comment: actually it's the same way that i did but it gives me the above exception

Comment: Your EJB is apparently not bound using the name `ejb/EjbServiceImpl`.  The `CNTR0167I` messages in SystemOut.log should tell you which binding name you should be using instead.

Comment: Try annotating "private EjbService eService" with @EJB in the controller class

Comment: On your `EjbServiceImpl`, you should have `@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/EjbServiceImpl")`. You then reference your EJB as you are doing it now: `<property name="jndiName" value="ejb/EjbServiceImpl">`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all whom trying help me, actually solved my problem in the following way

**Spring XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="springController" class="com.controllers.SpringController" scope="session">
    <property name="eService" ref="ejbService"/>                
    </bean>
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="ejbService" jndi-name="java:global/myEAR/myApp/EjbService">
    </jee:jndi-lookup> 
</beans>
```

**Spring controller**

```
public class SpringController {

    private EjbService eService;

    public void setOrders(Order order) { 
        eService.liquidPortfolio(order);
    }

    public EjbService  getEService() {
        return eService;
    }

    public void setEService (
        EjbService  eService) {
        this.eService = eService;
    }
}
```

**MY EJB**

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@Singleton
public class EjbService {

    @Asynchronous
    public void setOrders(Order order) {        
        System.out.println(" order=" + order);
    }   
}
```